# PostgreSQL function, need to get variables inside the function

Tags: function, postgresql, variables, plpgsql

I need some help with defining a Function in postgreSQL:

here are my table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE venue (
   id INTEGER DEFAULT NEXTVAL('venue_id_seq')
 , building_code building_code
 , floorNo int
 , roomNo int
 , width int
 , length int
);
```

I need to create a function related to that table that gives me the Floor area.Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE FUNCTION floorArea(id int) RETURNS int AS '
SELECT  venue.width * venue.length AS result ;
' LANGUAGE SQL;
```

I don't know how to possibly make variables etc.
I want something along the lines of:

```
var width=  Select width from venue where id=$1;
var length=  Select length from venue where id=$1;
return width * length;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like

```
CREATE FUNCTION floorArea(idp int)
RETURNS int
as
$$
    select width * length from venue as v where v.id = idp
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b34e9/1)

Comment: I make it a habit to prefix parameter names with `_`, like `_id`, to avoid conflicts altogether. It also helps to quickly identify parameter names in the code. Also, I also advise against unquoted CamelCase identifiers like `floorArea`. It leads to confusion easily. There have been several desperate questions here, stemming from that.

Comment: I'm working with SQL Server at my job, PostgreSQL only fo fun (although I'd like to work with PostgreSQL), so we always have @ before parameters. Anyway, thanks for tip

Answer (score 2):

There are no variables inside an **SQL** function. You need to use [**PL/pgSQL**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html) or [**another procedural language**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xplang.html) for that.

With plpgsql it could look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION floor_area(_id int)
  RETURNS int AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _width   int;
   _length  int;
BEGIN

SELECT INTO _width, _length
             width,  length
FROM   venue
WHERE  id = _id;

RETURN width * length;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Consider what I wrote about [parameter names in my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235496/postgresql-return-a-function-with-a-custom-data-type/18235894#18235894).

But a simple task like this should be solved with plain SQL without variables like [@Roman already supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18234240/939860).