# PostgreSQL return a function with a Custom Data Type

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, plpgsql

I want to create a function that returns a type that I made, but when I execute it, it says that the type doesn't exists. I assume that's cause it doesn't know about the custom type.

UDT:

```
CREATE TYPE building_code AS ENUM ('IT','EMS','HSB','ENG');
```

Function:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION roomCode(id int ) RETURNS building_code AS 
$$
 SELECT building_code FROM venue as v WHERE id = v.id;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Comment: Missing: Postgres version, verbatim error message, table definition.

Comment: you've called your column name exactly like you type - I'd suggest to avoid that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should just work. The `enum` should not be a problem. Tested with Postgres 9.1 and 9.2

```
CREATE TYPE building_code AS ENUM ('IT','EMS','HSB','ENG');
CREATE TEMP TABLE venue (id int PRIMARY KEY, building_code building_code);
INSERT INTO venue VALUES (1, 'ENG');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION room_code(_id int) --!
  RETURNS building_code AS 
$func$
SELECT building_code FROM venue v WHERE v.id = $1 -- !
$func$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT * FROM room_code(1);
```

**Except** ...

- In versions **before 9.2** you can only use [**positional (numeric) parameters** (`$1`)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-PARAMETERS) in SQL functions (unlike plpgsql functions).
  In **9.2+** the column name would take precedence, so that the `WHERE` clause of your original code would always be TRUE and all rows would qualify - except that your function only returns the first, since it does not return a `SETOF building_code`.
  Either rename your parameter or use positional parameter or, preferably, both.
  If you must use conflicting parameter names, you can override the preference by using the function name to qualify the parameter. Like:

  ```
  ... WHERE v.id = room_code.id
  ```
- You shouldn't use the type name as column name.
- You should not use unquoted mixed case names like `roomCode`, which will be folded to lower case, unless you double-quote: `"roomCode"`.

[**->SQLfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ebe88/2) with 3 variants

Comment: does `select ... from venue where v.id = id` will treat unaliased id as parameter or as column from venue?

Comment: @RomanPekar: Good point. You can't use the parameter name *at all* in versions before 9.2. Only positional parameters. In 9.2+ the column name takes precedence. I amended my answer.

Comment: thanks, @ErwinBrandstetter, so you either use positional or rename parameters. Will know :)