# Returning result set from Postgres functions

Tags: postgresql, function, user-defined-functions, plpgsql, set-returning-functions

In my Postgres 9.2 database, I need to build a function that takes several parameters, performs several queries, and then returns a data set that is composed of several rows and several columns. I've built several test functions to get a better grasp of Postgres' functionality, here is one:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sql_with_rows11(id integer) RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
 declare vid integer;
 declare vendor character varying;
BEGIN
 vid := (select v_id from public.gc_alerts where a_id = id);
 vendor := (select v_name from public.gc_vendors where v_id = vid);
 
 RETURN vendor;
END;
$BODY$
   LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I know that I can combine this into one query, but this is more of a practice exercise. This works fine and I get the vendor name. However, I need to return more than one column from the `gc_vendors` table.

Ultimately, I need to return columns from several tables based on subqueries. I've looked into creating a result set function, but I believe it only returns one row at a time. I also looked into returning `setof type`, but that seems to be limited to existing  tables.

After initial feedback, I changed the function to the following:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sql_with_rows14(IN v_uid character varying, IN lid           integer) 
 RETURNS table (aid int, aname character varying) AS
$BODY$
 declare aid integer;
 declare aname character varying;
BEGIN
 sql_with_rows14.aid := (select a_id from public.gc_alerts where v_id =           sql_with_rows14.v_uid);
 sql_with_rows14.aname := (select a_name from public.gc_alerts where a_id =      sql_with_rows14.aid);

 RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
   LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I also tried `RETURN NEXT`, but same results.

When I query it, if the query returns only one row, it works fine. However it doesn't work for **multiple rows**. I also tried something like this, with the same result:

```sql
...
BEGIN
 sql_with_rows14.aid := (select a_id from public.gc_alerts);
 sql_with_rows14.aname := (select a_name from public.gc_alerts);
 
 RETURN NEXT;
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

> I need to return more than one column from the gc_vendors table

To return a **single row with multiple fields** (as opposed to a set of rows), you can either use:

```
RETURNS row_type
```

.. where *`row_type`* is a pre-defined composite type (like a table name, that serves as such automatically). Or:

```
RETURNS record
```

combined with `OUT` parameters. Be aware that `OUT` parameters are visible in the body almost everywhere and avoid [naming conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235496/postgresql-return-a-function-with-a-custom-data-type/18235894#18235894).
Using the second option, your function could look like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sql_with_columns(IN  _id integer   -- IN is optional default
                                          , OUT vid integer
                                          , OUT vendor text)
  RETURNS record
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO vid  v_id
   FROM   public.gc_alerts
   WHERE  a_id = id;

   SELECT INTO vendor  v_name
   FROM   public.gc_vendors
   WHERE  v_id = vid;

   RETURN;     -- just noise, since OUT parameters are returned automatically
END
$func$;
```

As you mentioned, you should combine both queries into one, or even use a plain SQL statement instead. This is just a show case. [The excellent manual has all the details.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html)

You can also use:

```
RETURNS TABLE (...)
```

Or:

```
RETURNS SETOF row_type
```

This allows to return a **set of rows** (0, 1 or many). But that's not in your question.

To get individual columns instead of a record representation, **call** the function with:

```
SELECT * FROM sql_with_columns(...);
```

There are lots of examples here on SO, [try a search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plpgsql+set-returning-functions) - maybe with additional key words.

Also read the chapter [*"Returning from a Function"*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) in the manual.

Comment: I believe the final "RETURN;" can be omitted in the "sql_with_columns" function.

Comment: @bma: My comment there says as much, doesn't it? [Pavel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/406691/pavel-stehule) (major contributor to plpgsql) prefers an explicit `RETURN`, even if not needed like in the example.

Comment: It does. I shouldn't have mentioned that, it was obvious from your "noise" comment that it served no purpose. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, consider using views or simple queries. I'd say that if you can process something with a simple query, you shouldn't create function for that. in your case, you can use this query

```
select
    v.v_name, v.* -- or any other columns from gc_alerts or gc_vendors
from public.gc_alerts as a
    inner join public.gc_vendors as v on v.v_id = a.vid
where a.a_id = <your id here>
```

if you want your function to return rows, you can declare it like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sql_with_rows11(id integer)
RETURNS table(vendor text, v_id int)
as
$$
    select
        v.v_name, v.v_id
    from public.gc_alerts as a
        inner join public.gc_vendors as v on v.v_id = a.vid
    where a.a_id = id
$$ language SQL;
```

or plpgsql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sql_with_rows11(id integer)
RETURNS table(vendor text, vid int)
AS
$$
    declare vid integer;
    declare vendor character varying;
BEGIN
    sql_with_rows11.vid := 1; -- prefix with function name because otherwise it would be declared variables
    sql_with_rows11.vendor := 4;
    return next; 

    sql_with_rows11.vid := 5;
    sql_with_rows11.vendor := 8;
    return next;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b7e40/1) to fiddle with :)

Comment: Hi Roman, your answer is very helpful. I tried to write something similar, but I have a problem returning multiple rows. I have the following

Comment: @user2630270 following what?