# function return setof text

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, greenplum

I'm newby to PG/GP.
I need write function returning a full Greenplum table definition (like in dbeaver DDL tab). In my system functions `get_table_def`, `catalog.pg_gettabledef` does not exist, or unavailable to me.
I don't know why, maybe insufficient user rights.

I already find a function, which returns `setof text` with table structure definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION describe_table(p_schema_name varchar, p_table_name varchar)
    RETURNS SETOF text
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    VOLATILE
AS $$
    
DECLARE
    v_table_ddl   text;
    column_record record;
    table_rec record;
    constraint_rec record;
    firstrec boolean;
BEGIN
    FOR table_rec IN
        SELECT c.relname, c.oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
            LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
                WHERE relkind = 'r'
                AND n.nspname = p_schema_name
                AND relname~ ('^('||p_table_name||')$')
          ORDER BY c.relname
    LOOP
        FOR column_record IN
            SELECT
                b.nspname as schema_name,
                b.relname as table_name,
                a.attname as column_name,
                pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) as column_type,
                CASE WHEN
                    (SELECT substring(pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid) for 128)
                     FROM pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d
                     WHERE d.adrelid = a.attrelid AND d.adnum = a.attnum AND a.atthasdef) IS NOT NULL THEN
                    'DEFAULT '|| (SELECT substring(pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid) for 128)
                                  FROM pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d
                                  WHERE d.adrelid = a.attrelid AND d.adnum = a.attnum AND a.atthasdef)
                ELSE
                    ''
                END as column_default_value,
                CASE WHEN a.attnotnull = true THEN
                    'NOT NULL'
                ELSE
                    'NULL'
                END as column_not_null,
                a.attnum as attnum,
                e.max_attnum as max_attnum
            FROM
                pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
                INNER JOIN
                 (SELECT c.oid,
                    n.nspname,
                    c.relname
                  FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
                       LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
                  WHERE c.oid = table_rec.oid
                  ORDER BY 2, 3) b
                ON a.attrelid = b.oid
                INNER JOIN
                 (SELECT
                      a.attrelid,
                      max(a.attnum) as max_attnum
                  FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
                  WHERE a.attnum > 0
                    AND NOT a.attisdropped
                  GROUP BY a.attrelid) e
                ON a.attrelid=e.attrelid
            WHERE a.attnum > 0
              AND NOT a.attisdropped
            ORDER BY a.attnum
        LOOP
            IF column_record.attnum = 1 THEN
                v_table_ddl:='CREATE TABLE '||column_record.schema_name||'.'||column_record.table_name||' (';
            ELSE
                v_table_ddl:=v_table_ddl||',';
            END IF;

            IF column_record.attnum <= column_record.max_attnum THEN
                v_table_ddl:=v_table_ddl||chr(10)||
                         '    '||column_record.column_name||' '||column_record.column_type||' '||column_record.column_default_value||' '||column_record.column_not_null;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;

        firstrec := TRUE;
        FOR constraint_rec IN
            SELECT conname, pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid) as constrainddef
                FROM pg_constraint c
                    WHERE conrelid=(
                        SELECT attrelid FROM pg_attribute
                        WHERE attrelid = (
                            SELECT oid FROM pg_class WHERE relname = table_rec.relname
                                AND relnamespace = (SELECT ns.oid FROM pg_namespace ns WHERE ns.nspname = p_schema_name)
                        ) AND attname='tableoid'
                    )
        LOOP
            v_table_ddl:=v_table_ddl||','||chr(10);
            v_table_ddl:=v_table_ddl||'CONSTRAINT '||constraint_rec.conname;
            v_table_ddl:=v_table_ddl||chr(10)||'    '||constraint_rec.constrainddef;
            firstrec := FALSE;
        END LOOP;
        v_table_ddl:=v_table_ddl||');';
        RETURN NEXT v_table_ddl;
    END LOOP;
END;

$$
EXECUTE ON ANY;
```

Now I want to write another similar function, which returns `setof text` based on select with 3 rows dataset (other part DDL of Greenplum table which consist partitions info):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION kasudra_dds.describe_table1(p_schema_name varchar, p_table_name varchar)
    RETURNS SETOF text
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    VOLATILE
AS $$
    
DECLARE
    v_table_ddl   text;
    column_record record;
    table_rec record;
    constraint_rec record;
    firstrec boolean;
BEGIN
    FOR table_rec IN
        select
            n.nspname as schemaname,
            c.relname as tablename,
            a.attname as columnname,
            p.parlevel as partitionlevel,
            p.i + 1 as position_in_partition_key
        from
            pg_namespace n,
            pg_class c,
            pg_attribute a,
            (
            select
                p.parrelid,
                p.parlevel,
                p.paratts[i.i] as attnum,
                i.i
            from
                pg_partition p,
                generate_series(0,
                (
                select
                    max(array_upper(pg_partition.paratts, 1)) as max
                from
                    pg_partition)) i(i)
            where
                p.paratts[i.i] is not null) p
        where
            p.parrelid = c.oid      and 
            c.relnamespace = n.oid  and 
            p.attnum = a.attnum     and 
            a.attrelid = c.oid      and 
            n.nspname = $1          and 
            c.relname = $2
        order by
            p.parlevel
    LOOP
        v_table_ddl:=v_table_ddl||'PARTITION BY LIST ('||table_rec.columnname||')'||chr(10);
        RETURN NEXT v_table_ddl;
    END LOOP;
END;

$$
EXECUTE ON ANY;
```

But it returns 3 rows with `null` values, instead of `setof text`.

[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI0n1.png)
[trouble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di9dw.png)

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: without having data and tables  and actual and wanted result nobody can help you see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please clarify your desired result. And declare your version of Greenplum.

Answer (score 0):

You get `null` because you did not init the variable `v_table_ddl`, so it defaults to `null`. And `null || anything` is `null`.

```
v_table_ddl   text := '';  -- init to empty string
```

In the `DECLARE` section would fix that.

But the whole function seems very convoluted. I doubt you want to return `setof text` to begin with. Looks like you just want to return a single concatenated `text` value. And you most probably don't need the loop either.

The template function doesn't seem very mature, either. For one, it concatenates identifiers without proper double-quoting, which opens you up to syntax errors and SQL-injection with names that would require double-quoting. See:

- [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384159/define-table-and-column-names-as-arguments-in-a-plpgsql-function/18386034#18386034)

And at least the inner loop could be replaced with aggregation in plain SQL.

To get a re-engineered `CREATE TABLE` script in Postgres, use pgAdmin (or any GUI that does it), or `pg_dump` from the shell:

```
pg_dump db_name -t 'schema_name.table_name' --schema-only --no-owner --no-acl --no-comments --no-tablespaces
```

Related:

- [How to generate the "create table" sql statement for an existing table in postgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593803/how-to-generate-the-create-table-sql-statement-for-an-existing-table-in-postgr)

Finally, remember to call set-returning functions with `SELECT * FROM ...`. See:

- [Returning result set from Postgres functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404985/returning-result-set-from-postgres-functions/18406381#18406381)
- [Record returned from function has columns concatenated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392371/record-returned-from-function-has-columns-concatenated/25392910#25392910)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
You're right. I just want to return a single concatenated text value. But why a first function, which also RETURNS SETOF text, return only single text?

Comment: @Babo: The first function returns one row (with one text column) per qualifying table. `WHERE relname~ ('^('||p_table_name||')$')` of the first `SELECT` effectively allows regexp wildcards, so many tables can qualify. Try the call: `SELECT * FROM describe_table('public', 'p.*')` to get definitions for all tables starting with "p".