# Postgres error in creating a function

Tags: sql, postgresql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create a function in Postgres as follows:

```
Create function Samplefunc() 
returns resultdata( Tested int, Score int,
       Growth int) as
$BODY$
Select 
       Count(distinct student_id) Tested, 
       Cast(Avg(R.raw_score) as Int)  Score,
       Avg(R.growth) as Growth
from results R
where R.id=1 and test_id='ME04';
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "int"
LINE 2: returns resultdata( NTested int, RawScore int,
                                    ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "int"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 59
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION samplefunc() 
  RETURNS TABLE(ntested int, rawscore int, growth int) AS
$func$
SELECT count(DISTINCT r.student_id) -- AS NTested
      ,avg(r.raw_score)::int        -- AS RawScore
      ,avg(r.growth)::int           -- AS Growth
FROM   reports_results r
WHERE  r.test_type_id = 1
AND    r.test_id = '201403MAME04'
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

- The clause to return a table is [**`RETURNS TABLE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html).
- Carefully avoid conflicts between `OUT` parameters and column names. (I had such a conflict in my first draft). Table-qualify columns to disambiguate.
  All field names in `RETURNS TABLE` are effectively `OUT` parameters and visible inside the function (almost) everywhere.

Also:

- `avg(growth)` would result in a type mismatch with the declared return type `int`. You need to cast that, too. Using the short [Postgres-specific syntax `::type`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS), btw.
  Better yet: return [`numeric` or a floating point number](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) to preserve fractional digits in your avg numbers.
- column aliases are only visible inside the function. If you are not going to reference them *inside* the function, they are just documentation.
- What's with the capitalization? [Unquoted identifiers are cast to lower case in Postgres automatically.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

**If** the query is guaranteed to return a *single* row, you might want to combine `OUT` parameters with `RETURNS record`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION samplefunc(OUT ntested int, OUT rawscore int, OUT growth int) 
  RETURNS record  AS ...
```

The subtle difference: This way you get a single row with `NULL` values if nothing is found, where the first form would return nothing / no row.

#### Add IN parameters (request in comment)

```
CREATE FUNCTION samplefunc(_test_type_id int, _test_id text) 
  RETURNS TABLE(ntested int, rawscore int, growth int) AS
$func$
SELECT count(DISTINCT r.student_id)
      ,avg(r.raw_score)::int
      ,avg(r.growth)::int
FROM   reports_results r
WHERE  r.test_type_id = $1   -- or: = _test_type_id in Postgres 9.2+
AND    r.test_id = $2        -- or: = _test_id
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Many related answers here on SO with more code examples. Like:

- [PostgreSQL return a function with a Custom Data Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235496/postgresql-return-a-function-with-a-custom-data-type/18235894#18235894)

[Try a search.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgres%5D%20%5Bplpgsql%5D%20CREATE%20FUNCTION%20parameter%20%22RETURNS%20TABLE%22)

Comment: hi..thanks for the answer. it worked great! how do i modify it to pass some arguments such that i dont have to define it like "where R.test_type_id=1 and test_id='201403MAME04';" anymore?

Comment: @crozzfire: I added another answer to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try not specifying the details of the composite return type. However, I think the return structure must exist first.

```
Create table resultdata (NTested int, RawScore int, Growth int);

Create function Samplefunc() returns resultdata as
$BODY$
Select 
   Count(distinct student_id) as NTested, 
   Cast(Avg(R.raw_score) as Int) as RawScore,
   Avg(R.growth) as Growth
from reports_results R
where R.test_type_id=1 and test_id='201403MAME04';
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Or try explicitly returning a table:

```
Create function Samplefunc() 
    returns Table (NTested int, RawScore int, Growth int) as
$BODY$
Select 
   Count(distinct student_id) as NTested, 
   Cast(Avg(R.raw_score) as Int) as RawScore,
   Avg(R.growth) as Growth
from reports_results R
where R.test_type_id=1 and test_id='201403MAME04';
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

I think you can also return a set of records using output parameters:

```
Create function Samplefunc(OUT NTested int, OUT RawScore int, OUT Growth int) 
    returns SetOf Record as
$BODY$
Select 
   Count(distinct student_id) as NTested, 
   Cast(Avg(R.raw_score) as Int) as RawScore,
   Avg(R.growth) as Growth
from reports_results R
where R.test_type_id=1 and test_id='201403MAME04';
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return a record containing multiple output parameters. You should do like:

```
Create function Samplefunc(out NTested int, out RawScore int, out Growth int) as
$BODY$
Select 
       Count(distinct student_id) NTested, 
       Cast(Avg(R.raw_score) as Int)  RawScore,
       Avg(R.growth) as Growth
from reports_results R
where R.test_type_id=1 and test_id='201403MAME04';
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

You can do the same thing more verbosely with an explicitly named composite type; like

```
CREATE TYPE resultdata AS (NTested int, RawScore int, Growth int);

CREATE FUNCTION Samplefunc() RETURNS resultdata
    AS .......
```

Or using a `TABLE` function like

```
CREATE FUNCTION Samplefunc() RETURNS TABLE(NTested int, RawScore int, Growth int)
AS
......
```

See [PostgreSQL Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) for more information on the same

Answer (score 0):

If you have not defined a type "resultset" as Luke rightly assumed, then try returning a table instead.

```
Create function Samplefunc() 
returns table( NTested int, RawScore int,
       Growth int) as
$BODY$
Select 
       Count(distinct student_id) NTested, 
       Cast(Avg(R.raw_score) as Int)  RawScore,
       Avg(R.growth) as Growth
from reports_results R
where R.test_type_id=1 and test_id='201403MAME04';
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```